# Streamlining/Optimizing a T-SQL query that has the same content but diff. where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I'm trying to merge my code that has almost the same structure but different where clauses. The only thing I did as of now was to union them.

Here's a snippet my code:

```
insert into #tempAging
    select 
        mm0.transid, max(mm0.mi) as Mi,  
        CASE 
            when (max(mm0.DueDate) > @StatementDate) 
               then 
                  case  
                     when sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt, 0)) = 0 
                        then '01 CURRENT AND NEW ACCOUNTS'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt, 0)))  / (max(mm0.MI))) > 0) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt, 0))) / (max(mm0.MI))) <= 1) )) 
                        then '02 ONE(1) MONTH'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 1 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=2) )) 
                        then '03 TWO(2) MONTHS'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 2 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=3) )) 
                        then '04 THREE(3) MONTHS'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 3 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=4) )) 
                        then '05 FOUR(4) MONTHS'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 4 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=5) )) 
                        then '06 FIVE(5) MONTHS'
                     when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 5 )) 
                        then '07 SIX(6) MONTHS'
                  end
               else 
                  case 
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 0 
                        then '09 LAPCON ONE(1) MONTH'
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 1 
                        then '10 LAPCON TWO(2) MONTHS'
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 2 
                        then '11 LAPCON THREE(3) MONTHS'
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 3 
                        then '12 LAPCON FOUR(4) MONTHS'
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 4 
                        then '13 LAPCON FIVE(5) MONTHS'
                     when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) >= 5 
                        then '14 LAPCON SIX(6) MONTHS'
                  end        
        END AS Aging                
    from
        (select 
             e0.transid, e0.DueDate,
             CASE
                when e0.DueDate > @StatementDate then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0))  
                else 0 
             end as CurrentBal,
             CASE
                when max(isnull(e0.Debit,0)) <> max(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) and max(e0.DueDate) <= @StatementDate 
                   then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) 
                else 0 
             end as OverDueAmt, 
             (select top 1 insTotal 
              from inv6 
              where objType = '13' 
                and DocEntry = max(e1.docentry)) as MI
         from 
             JDT1 e0 
         inner join 
             oinv e1 on e1.transid = e0.transid 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             (select TransID, TransRowID, ReconSum, LastReconDate 
              from #tempRecon) e2 ON e2.[TransId] = e0.[TransId] 
                                  AND  e2.[TransRowId] = e0.[Line_ID]
        left outer join 
            OACT e3 on e3.AcctCode = e0.Account
        where 
            isnull(e0.transcode, '') not in (N'BEG', N'ADJ') 
            and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210'
        group by 
            e0.transid, e0.line_id, e0.DueDate) mm0
    group by 
        mm0.transid

UNION ALL

select mm0.transid, max(mm0.mi) as Mi,
CASE when ( max(mm0.DueDate) > @StatementDate) then
case    when  sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)) = 0 then '01 CURRENT AND NEW ACCOUNTS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 0 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=1) )) then '02 ONE(1) MONTH'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 1 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=2) )) then '03 TWO(2) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 2 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=3) )) then '04 THREE(3) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 3 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=4) )) then '05 FOUR(4) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 4 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=5) )) then '06 FIVE(5) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 5 )) then '07 SIX(6) MONTHS'
end
else 
case
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 0 then '09 LAPCON ONE(1) MONTH'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 1 then '10 LAPCON TWO(2) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 2 then '11 LAPCON THREE(3) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 3 then '12 LAPCON FOUR(4) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 4 then '13 LAPCON FIVE(5) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) >= 5 then '14 LAPCON SIX(6) MONTHS'
end  
END  as Aging               
from
( select e0.transid, e0.DueDate,  
CASE
when e0.DueDate > @StatementDate then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0))  else 0 end  as CurrentBal,
CASE
when max(isnull(e0.Debit,0)) <> max(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) and max(e0.DueDate) <= @StatementDate then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) else 0 end as OverDueAmt, 
(select  top 1 insTotal from inv6 where objType = '13' and DocEntry = max(e1.docentry)) as MI
from JDT1 e0 
inner join oinv e1 on e1.transid = e0.transid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select TransID, TransRowID, ReconSum, LastReconDate from #tempRecon) e2 ON  e2.[TransId] = e0.[TransId] AND  e2.[TransRowId] = e0.[Line_ID]
left outer join OACT e3 on e3.AcctCode = e0.Account
where isnull(e0.transcode,'') in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210' and e0.TransType = N'30'
group by e0.transid, e0.line_id, e0.DueDate) mm0
group by mm0.transid
```

I hope someone can help me. TIA!

Comment: Is the only difference this line: `and e0.TransType = N'30'`? If that is the csae, the first set of data will _already_ include `TransType = N'30'` and your second set of data will only include `TransType = N'30'` so you're going to get double ups.

Comment: Yes. The only difference is and "e0.TransType = N'30'". So is it safe to merge both codes and the include "and e0.TransType = N'30'"?

Comment: when you add `and e0.TransType = N'30'"`, it limits the data to _only_ those records with `TransType = N'30'"`. So this will exclude records with TransType of 1 ,2, 3, 4 etc. I don't know what you're trying to do but so far it doesn't make sense. I suggest you only use the first part of the union, then inspect the output data and you'll see it **already** includes records with `TransType = N'30'"`. You need to inspect the data and work out what you want. Currently you're getting all the data then you're getting an extra copy of just transtype 30 records

Comment: Alright. I'll get back at you after I finish running the code. Thanks for the reply sir Nick!

Comment: OK so based on the answer below, this is *not* the only difference

Comment: You need to learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your issue - this is just waaaaaaaay too much code to handle!

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need, from what I understand, is to club the two logical expressions into one and avoid the union.

```
where isnull(e0.transcode,'') not in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210'

OR

where isnull(e0.transcode,'') in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210' and e0.TransType = N'30'
```

is basically a,

```
(A and B and C) or ((not A) and B)
```

Since this is already in its simplest form [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A%20AND%20B%20AND%20C)%20%20OR%20(NOT%20A%20AND%20B)), you can just use

```
where (isnull(e0.transcode,'') not in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210') or (isnull(e0.transcode,'') in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210' and e0.TransType = N'30')
```

in the first select and remove the second part of the Union.

So your final query will look like:

```
insert into #tempAging
select mm0.transid, max(mm0.mi) as Mi,  
CASE when ( max(mm0.DueDate) > @StatementDate) then
case    when  sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)) = 0 then '01 CURRENT AND NEW ACCOUNTS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 0 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=1) )) then '02 ONE(1) MONTH'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 1 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=2) )) then '03 TWO(2) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 2 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=3) )) then '04 THREE(3) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 3 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=4) )) then '05 FOUR(4) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 4 ) AND ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) <=5) )) then '06 FIVE(5) MONTHS'
when ((((sum(isnull(mm0.OverDueAmt,0)))/(max(mm0.MI))) > 5 )) then '07 SIX(6) MONTHS'
end
else 
case when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 0 then '09 LAPCON ONE(1) MONTH'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 1 then '10 LAPCON TWO(2) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 2 then '11 LAPCON THREE(3) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 3 then '12 LAPCON FOUR(4) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) = 4 then '13 LAPCON FIVE(5) MONTHS'
when DATEDIFF(month, max(mm0.DueDate) , @StatementDate) >= 5 then '14 LAPCON SIX(6) MONTHS'

end      
END  as Aging               

from
( select e0.transid, e0.DueDate,
CASE
when e0.DueDate > @StatementDate then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0))  else 0 end  as CurrentBal,
CASE
when max(isnull(e0.Debit,0)) <> max(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) and max(e0.DueDate) <= @StatementDate then sum(e0.debit) - sum(isnull(e2.ReconSum,0)) else 0 end as OverDueAmt, 
(select  top 1 insTotal from inv6 where objType = '13' and DocEntry = max(e1.docentry)) as MI
from JDT1 e0 
inner join oinv e1 on e1.transid = e0.transid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select TransID, TransRowID, ReconSum, LastReconDate from #tempRecon) e2 ON  e2.[TransId] = e0.[TransId] AND  e2.[TransRowId] = e0.[Line_ID]
left outer join OACT e3 on e3.AcctCode = e0.Account
where (isnull(e0.transcode,'') not in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210') or (isnull(e0.transcode,'') in (N'BEG',N'ADJ') and e3.Segment_0 = N'11210' and e0.TransType = N'30')
group by e0.transid, e0.line_id, e0.DueDate) mm0
group by mm0.transid
```